# ejabberd file transfer fail

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

pls hlp me to over come this error  am using windows system

@ejabberd_pkix:handle_call:175 No certificate found matching 'esat.ae': strictly configured clients or servers will reject connections with this host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you need to obtain a certificate for this domain from any trusted CA, such as Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add your certificate file first